# Multithreading inside java servlets

Tags: servlets, threadpoolexecutor

In my application a user can create data-filters on all defined applications, I have decided to make this task execute on a different thread since processing all applications might take a while. I'm using a:

`private static final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();`

```
public static JSON createFilter(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp){
...
// some type checking then apply filters   
...
for(Integer appId : appIds){
        executor.execute(new ApplyFilterTask(appId));
        }
}
```

my ApplyFilterTask is simple:

```
private static class ApplyFilterTask implements Runnable{

    private static ManagerService ms = null;
    int appId;


    public ApplyFilterTask(int appId) {
        this.appId = appId;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (ms == null){
            ms = new ManagementService();
            }
        try {
            ms.applyFilters(appId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // log the error
        }
}
```

I would like to have the following behavior, when a user creates a new filter, a new thread will start and process all the applications one-by-one (it's okay for this second thread to take a while) and then i suppose kill the thread (to save resources)

my problems are:

- i don't know where to put `executor.shutdown();` in my code
- what happens if during the process another user creates a filter? how can i get my servlet to use the same thread or at least wait until the first one is done before creating another?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the spec has changed, but you're really not supposed to be using threads in your servlet code: http://www.coderanch.com/mobile/t/535749/Servlets/java/Threads-Servlets?foo=a.

You should scale using your container, or if you need to introduce asynchronous processing use out of process workers and a message queue of some sort.